# Migrate Sinon 7 to 8

Tags: sinon

I am using node 12.14.1, karma 4.4.1 and sinon 7.5.0
I Want to update sinon to the latest version (8.1.1), but I got this error:

```
28 01 2020 12:03:52.901:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
28 01 2020 12:03:52.904:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers PhantomJS with concurrency unlimited
28 01 2020 12:03:53.045:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
28 01 2020 12:03:56.249:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0)]: Connected on socket nWUU_e4J9lEni4AFAAAA with id 124
2
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map
  at node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:4113:35
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map
  at node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:4113:35
```

What do I need to change or include? I tried to include es6-shim but that does not work.